# What if the Accompanying Voice is internal and non-mystical, yet mistakenly is the basis for Religion?

Tags: epistemology, theology, psychology

Some small proportion of people (you know who you are) have an Accompanying Voice: an equal who converses with your "normal thought voice" whenever you have questions or problems that you cannot solve, or just feel like having a chat. This is not a delusion, hallucination, or aberrant, problematic or even unusual (about 4% of people, according to research).

So my question is: **What if people have misunderstood the nature and origin of the Accompanying Voice and attributed it to something external (such as, for example, God)?** This has nothing to do with whether or not God in fact *is*, and nothing to do with Psychology, Cognitive Science, Marketing, or other disreputable pursuits.

As a Philosophical proposal, what would we now know and be able to declare "understood and closed to further inquiry", if:

*The Accompanying Voice in some people (and a variety of non-verbal senses, experiences and impulses in nearly everyone else) was definitively, irrefutably, categorically* proven *to be a manifestation of an inner guidance system that we have not yet fully understood, but which is not mystical, not non-self, etc.?*

Comment: The question in the post is not the same as the question in the header.  The post question "what if the accompanying voice is internal AND nonmystical?"  The header question is "what if the accompanying voice is responsible for religion?"  I'm assuming your real question is "what if the (sole?) basis for religion was demonstrated to be internal, nonmystical experiences?"  Please rewrite to clarify --I'll hold off on close-voting to allow you that chance.  You'll also need to do some work to prevent this from soliciting purely opinion based answers.

Comment: @ChrisSunami "*Better 1, or 2?*"

Comment: I'm afraid, based on your comments, I have to vote to close.  You're just proposing two counterfactuals and asking for conclusions.  Since anything logically follows from a counterfactual, there's no non-opinion based answer possible.

Comment: @ChrisSunami in what sense are the two assertions counterfactual? Do you know something that I don't?

Comment: Based on your comments, your two assumptions are (a) "if religion were based on nothing but the accompanying voice" and (b) "if the accompanying voice were provably free of all divine influence".  (A) is controversial at best, you're presenting it as pure conjecture.  (B) is not even theoretically possible unless you have a much more tightly defined portrait of God, for reasons I'll explain below (comment to my answer).  So you have a conjecture plus an impossibility, the answer is an opinion.

Comment: You are arguing negatively (I'm trying to prove that something isn't happening) and I am arguing positively: assume something, see where it leads. If it explains and is not a contradiction, it is a candidate to be true. "*...However improbable...*"

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking your underlying question as "what if there were shown to be naturalistic causes for phenomenon typically taken as support for religion?"  The answer depends on whether your faith or your theology demands that God act in ways that are provably supernatural.  That isn't necessarily the case for all (or even necessarily most) believers.

Imagine a writer writing a book.  She writes some characters who converse with themselves inside their heads.  In some cases, she uses those internal conversations to advance her own beliefs and positions.  Within the "reality" of the book, there's nothing to distinguish between one internal conversation and another, but those who discern the authorial voice in some of those conversations are not wrong (even, or perhaps especially in the case where the opinions expressed are also true to the actual views of the character).

Comment: Let me see if I understand: you propose that some people would be OK with the idea that God influences their thoughts, which sometimes feels to them like an internal conversation? I was saying rather the opposite: what if we could prove that all such internal conversations were definitely *not* influenced by God? And: what if we could be quite sure that the basis for Religions was a *mistaken impression* that these internal experiences *were* the result of Divine influence? It requires both premises. To use your analogy, what if the internal character voices learned that they are not written?

Comment: How could you prove such a thing?  It's an impossible counterfactual.  What if I had a million dollars and a horse that could fly?

Comment: As far as the concept, it's not that God sometimes influences internal conversations, it's that internal conversations, just like everything else, are created by God (in this belief system) --accordingly their shape reflects the will of God even if they proceed in an entirely and provably naturalist manner.

Comment: But the world is just as consistent and unaltered if we realize what I am saying. I think that you mean 'unprovable' rather than 'counterfactual'. If you posed the only attempt to answer and you are voting to close solely on the basis of this interaction, I submit to you that you have a conflict of interest and are not in a position to vote to close. But if two or more of you gather to gather and say it, then it must be the case.

Comment: "Counterfactual" just means a conjecture that doesn't match reality, not necessarily a logical impossibility.  However, in this case, this counterfactual is impossible --one cannot, by naturalistic processes, *disprove* a God capable of acting through naturalistic processes (it's notoriously difficult to prove a negative). It's not the world without that God that is logically impossible, it's the world that can *prove* it lacks that God.  If you are willing to rule out that conception of God *a priori* then you might have more of an argument here, but you'd arguably be begging the question.

Comment: I don't think that proving that something arises naturally in the mind without divine intervention requires proving a negative. I can show that someone made my car, and this does not require proving that God *did not* make my car. Showing a natural cause or condition is not impossible, or even against religion, it is just empirical. Showing that a voice arises in the mind naturally and not through divine intervention is no different from showing that the sun rises because the earth turns and not because God made it happen. I think you are looking at this wrongly for some reason.

Comment: Re: The VTC --I'm not a mod here, so I can't close a question unilaterally.  As a member in good standing of the community, I'm in a position to vote to close by definition.  FWIW, I try not to vote to close based on personal opinions or interactions with the querent, but only on the basis of whether the question is a good fit for this SE format and the local on-topic guidelines (or can be edited to be one).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41876/discussion-between-chris-sunami-and-no-comprende).

Comment: Forgive me if I am inferring, but it seems as though your interest is not solely Philosophical. I was not trying to provoke anyone, just ask about an interesting idea I had this morning: What if Moses (and others, like Mohammed) mistook an inner voice for God? I have never done that, but it is easy for me to imagine. Few people have the experience I have with this, so not many are in a position to ask about it or understand it as a felt state. But other experiences of numenosity or whatever do occur. What if they are, as a friend said, "A feeling of euphoria with a wrong meaning ascription?"

Comment: I try to believe six impossible things before breakfast, but this one was so engrossing that I never did get to the others. Well, eleven for me tomorrow...

Comment: It's not a bad, or unphilosophical line of thought, but it's inherently speculative, which makes it a bad fit for StackExchange, regardless of it's merit. If you want to talk it over, the above link will take you to the chat room, which has less strict rules.  My line of response was not meant to be hostile, it was an attempt to see if the original question could be made more objective or not.  Part of productive philosophical inquiry is being clear on your underlying assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, John Nash, the mathematician relates in the biography by Sylvia Nasar that he heard voices, I don't recall whether he said that he had conversations with them.

However, when asked whether he gave them any credence, he answered by saying they come from the same place that his mathematical ideas come from.